# Use redis for object oriented proggramming

Tags: oop, redis, orm, cluster-analysis, online-game

I have created an online game which is written in object oriented programming and node.js . after clustering I decided to make these clusters stateless and save game objects in redis . How can that be done with keeping my game Class untouched ? Simply to save Game Objects with it's methods and props in redis and use those game object methods to update and read those game objects properties . I Have read about ORM but I guess i have to change my game Class to acheive this?

Comment: Do you need more than just storing the all object and reading it all? Or do you need to read part of the object or update one of the fields?

Comment: As it is an online game so i need to read one game object and update one or some of fields

Comment: oh sorry . i actually need to read all of the object and then read all of it and change it using my method and then save it again

Comment: So you can probably just store it as a simple serialized string in Redis, if you would like to avoid loading the all object and might be able to manipulate it in Redis I would have suggest you check the RedisJSON module.